# Creating a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

**(Question improved)**

Hello,
I'm trying to make a bookmarklet. Bookmarklet will be overlayed and will open right-top corner of page . You can see bookmarklet types [here][1] i want to make overlay interface.

Here is my javascript code for bookmarklet :

```
javascript:void((function(){var%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('src','http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/bookmarklet.js');document.body.appendChild(e)})())
```

Bookmarklet will call bookmarklet.js file. Content of bookmarklet.js :

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>";

document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='result' style='background-color:grey;z-index:1000;position:absolute;right:0;top:0' width='300' height='250'></div>";



var site = location.href;

    $.get("http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/c.php",{ q: site}, function(data){
                        $('.result').html(data);
                });
```

GET request sending i can see it via Firebug. But nothing returned.

Can you help me?

Comment: *What* does not work? It does work for me, but notice that this kind of bookmarklet obviously requires JQuery which is not available on every page you might access.

Comment: how it's working ? when i add this code directly firefox's bookmarks and then click return a page and **[object XMLHttpRequest]**

Comment: @poke , .get method JQUERY's method. So which method should i use for every webpages ?

Comment: Either you use a `XMLHttpRequest` directly (which is what happens when you use JQuery's `get`), or you load JQuery itself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the friendfeed bookmarklet you mentioned; all it does is create and append a new script tag that holds a js file with the 'real' functions.
The article you mentioned does the same. The basic (pretty selfexplaining) method is:

```
e=document.createElement('script');
e.type='text/javascript';
e.src='http://domain.tld/file.js'; //optionally pass GET params
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e); //optionally, you could append to the <body>
```

if you then take a closer look at the files that are included by this method you can see how the overlay is constructed. I pasted the important snippet from the [friendfeed file](https://friendfeed.com/share/bookmarklet/javascript), where the overlay div gets positioned, look for that section and study it:

```
// Create the share dialog in the corner of the window
var container = div();
container.id = "ff__container";
container.style.position = "absolute";
container.style.top = scrollPos().y + "px";
container.style.right = "0";
container.style.width = "auto";
container.style.zIndex = 100000;
```

so i would suggest that you make a separate js file that holds the functions for constructing the overlay and you let your bookmarklet load that file.

Comment: thank you i'm looking. But how can i send get request to **c.php** file via javascript (not jquery)

Comment: If you have a solution ready in jQuery, just include jQuery in the same way described above, otherwise i would read up on AJAX (XMLHttpRequest). Personally i have no experience yet with other requests from javascript, but the information is all out there, google it, seriously, you will save others from explaining over and over, and you will save yourself from waiting :)

Answer (score 1):

> when i add this code directly firefox's bookmarks and then click return a page and **[object XMLHttpRequest]**

This is a common problem with bookmarklets. To fix that add a `void(0);` to the end of the bookmarklet code. That way, the bookmarklet won't return any value which would be displayed in the browser.

Comment: *javascript:site=location.href;$.get("http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/c.php",{q:site},function(data){alert(data);void(0);* ?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of your bookmarklet.js is broken (as I'm writing this answer) because there's a missing quote after `var data =`.

Appart from that, I have several **untested theories** regarding your problem:

1. You're replacing the `body`'s `innerHTML` where your own script is running. And by the time the script finishes, jQuery isn't even loaded yet. You probably have to suspend the script's execution and wait for jQuery to load. Try something like putting your `$.get()` in a function that's called after a `window.setTimeout()`, and preferably that checks for the existence of `$` (with `typeof($) != 'undefined'`) and either waits more or runs your `$.get()`.
2. You're loading jQuery through HTTPS, so browser policies may prevent `$.get` from getting stuff from HTTP
3. Setting the jQuery `<script>` reference's `type` attribute to `text/javascript` shouldn't be your problem, but it definitely wouldn't hurt doing.

Comment: `var site = location.href;` where should be quote ? site variable is working . And this script doesn't working on jquery already loaded pages, too.

Comment: Script was different by then. Since you're using FF, you can open the error console (Tools -> Error Console) and you'll see the complaint on `$` not being defined. That's why I'm guessing it's either the missing `type="text/javascript"`, a timing issue or the different protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS).

Comment: added type="text/javascript but still same error. I'm adding JQUERY codes directly (you can see here : http://girmiyor.co.cc/bookmarklet.js) , now there isn't **$ isn't defined** error , but still doesn't working.